# Tfpdf with arabic charactre

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I am using `Tfpdf` to create a `PDF` file. This `PDF` file contains both Arabic word and English word. My problem is with the Arabic word.

The Arabic word is written from right to left.

The problem is I have a result with separate characters and the characters are written from left to right which make the word unreadable
[image].

This photo explain what I am trying to say.
The word in Arabic should be  `مرحبا` `بكم`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Tfpdf looks like it does not support right to left languages. I advice you to use tcpdf see https://tcpdf.org/  -> Main Features "UTF-8 Unicode and Right-To-Left languages;"

Comment: You Can use (https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_018/)